# Access cc.Director members and functions from utility file

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, game-engine, member, cocos2d-x-3.0

So I'm wanting to create a utility.js file that contains some actions and variables I know I'm going to need in several files. Specifically getting the width and height of the device.
I try using:

`var size = cc.Director.getInstance().getWinSize();`

But in the standalone file, it says the director is undefined. How can I access the director?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it. But I created a global var Utility in main.js. Then in the onstart() I added a line Utility = initUtility(); which is a function I created in my Utility file where I create my variables and methods.

Answer (score 1):

use cc.director instead of cc.Director.getInstance()

cocos2dx-js v3.x API is different from v2.x

> cc.Director.getInstance()           --> cc.director

here is the [offical document](https://github.com/chukong/cocos-docs/blob/master/manual/framework/html5/v3/singleton-objs/en.md)

Comment: var size = cc.director.getWinSize(); Gives me an error saying "Cannot read property 'getWinSize' of undefined"

Comment: it seems that the cocos engine has not been loaded yet? @DavidSmall

Comment: Then is there some kind of event I can listen for?